# Dynamically put textview above another view in relativelayout android

Tags: java, android, layout

Hi by doing java code i have done successfully add textview in relative layout like BOTTOM|RIGHT

but i want to put textview above bottom bar layout

here is the image
 [image]

here u can see that there is a textview which has white background image and its back it has black bottom baar i want to put textview above's bottom bar

Below is my java code

```
 LinearLayout bottomBar = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150, 70);
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, bottomBar.getId());
    butAddText.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

By doing this i have added bottom left but last two lines is not working i can not add textview above the bottom bar..

can any body help me please

Comment: r u want to enter any value in this textview else just use with image name display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you've set 2 conflicting rules.

Try to remove the next line:

```
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

The reason: you've tried to set the view to the bottom of its parent, and also above another view.

Comment: no if i remove Align_parent_bottom still nothing happen :( thanks andrid developer

Comment: have you tried to use addView(View,LayoutParams) instead of setting the layoutParams on the view ? i thought that both methods are the same, but maybe it's worth a shot. sadly i can't test it now, but your code seems fine, so maybe you could post some more code ?

Comment: No yar but finally i have put bottom margin 70 dp

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way may be **simulate** nested layouts:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
<TextView/>
<RelativeLayout/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But it may decrease performance.

**Edit:**

First inflate your LinearLayout(it's orientation is vertically) then add your TextView and your bottom bar.Also if you want to align TextView right,you can use a `RealtiveLayout` instead of outer LinearLayout.

Comment: No Hasanghaforian i want to put it through java code can u explain with java code?